# What is the proper way to implement retry behavior on a python client?

Tags: python

I often run into the task of writing some sort of wrapper for a python client. For example, I might write a wrapper for the Spotipy module to encapsulate credentials and/or specific data transformations etc. I also might write a wrapper for the requests module to interact with my api. Regardless, this is a common task...

One of the most common features that is part of writing these types of client, is some sort of retry behavior if the request fails. On the surface, this is a very simple task - you just encapsulate the request in a while loop that breaks when the request succeeds or the retry limit is reached. However, because I write so many methods and separate classes that all need this exact behavior, it's obviously something I'd rather turn into a decorator that I can implement in any client wrapper.

I imagine there's a standard way of doing this, given that it seems like one of the most common features of a client. Does anybody know of a good, clean way of implementing this behavior such that whenever I write a client method, I can just wrap it like so:

(This is pure pseudo-code, I know this doesn't work, this is just a way I might imagine it happening)

```
class Retry:
    def __init__(self, max_retries=3, delay=1):
        self.max_retries = max_retries
        self.delay = delay

    def __call__(self, func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            for i in range(self.max_retries):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    if i == self.max_retries - 1:  # If this was the last attempt
                        raise  # Re-raise the last exception
                    time.sleep(self.delay)  # Wait for a bit before retrying
        return wrapper

class MyAPIClass:
    def __init__(self, max_retries=3, delay=1):
        self.retry = Retry(max_retries, delay)

    @retry
    def method_that_might_fail(self):
        # Code that might raise an exception
        pass
```

The code fails because `@retry` is a class method which requires `self` as a parameter which isn't defined yet.

I've been trying to use chatGPT to figure out a method that works, but I keep going in circles always running into some sort of problem like this.

Does anybody know of a good clean way of decoupling the retry behavior so that it can be implemented in any client wrapper?

Comment: practically speaking, though, you should probably just use [tenacity](https://tenacity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Basically, though, this is a question about decorators. `@retry` is *not a class method*. You mean "instance method" but it isn't even an instance method. You are making `retry` and *instance attribute*. Since it is an instance attribute, it cannot be used in the class block. Why not make it a class attribute then?  Then the `wrapper` should rely on a convention of some instance attribute, e.g. `self.retries` which it handles mutating

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah I was looking into using tenacity, and totally fine with that, but i still can't seem to get a good implementation to work. The reason I'm doing it this way is because I want the "max_retries, etc" to be defined in the constructor of any client wrapper. if you know how to do this feel free to post an implementation

Answer (score 0):

It would be a simpler solution to implement 'retry' with a function.

```
from functools import partial, wraps
from random import random, seed
import time

def retry(func = None):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(self.max_retries):
            try:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                if i == self.max_retries - 1:
                    raise Exception
                time.sleep(self.delay)
    return wrapper
```

```
class MyAPIClass:
    def __init__(self, max_retries=3, delay=0.1):
        self.max_retries = max_retries
        self.delay = delay

    @retry
    def method_that_might_fail(self):
        # Code that might raise an exception
        if random() < 0.5: return random()
        else: raise Exception
```